# How to get doctrine2 table alias?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to create a method in my a Doctrine2 repository class that takes a QueryBuilder and adds some extra clauses, one of which is an inner join.

How can I find out the table alias that was used to instantiate the querybuilder? Is this something discoverable or should it be a convention across the codebase (and therefore a potential source of bugs)?

My client code is:

```
public function getPasswordAction($id)
{
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('TenKPwLockerBundle:Password');

    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id);

    $query = $repository->userCanReadRestriction($query, $user);
    ...
```

and my repository class contains:

```
public function userCanReadRestriction(\Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder $builder, \TenK\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
                             // where can I get 'p' from?
    return $builder->innerJoin('p.shares', 's')
        ->where('createdBy = :creator')
        ->orWhere('s.toUser = :toId')
        ->setParameters(array('creator' => $user, 'toUser' => $user));
}
```

In fact, in the above code, how can I confirm that the QueryBuilder is working with the Password Entity at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can retrive the `select` part of your QueryBuilder by calling the `getDqlPart('select')` method.

More information [here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L1028).

Then, look how doctrine does to parse select part [here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L1072).

You can probably do the same to know if the table associated to your repository is called and what is its alias.

Comment: Hmm... seems a bit hacky. Is there another way of doing this? How do people track QueryBuilder objects in their code?

Comment: I have downwoted this answer. I know its old, but that doesn't mater. Why i did that: first of all this is a link based answer, and actually says "go somewhere and figure things yourself", second of all, the links are pointing to the master branch  of repository, that means should repository's code change the line pointer will be incorrect (what is actually have happened already)

Answer (score 10):

The QueryBuilder object has two relevant methods:
- getRootAliases()
- getRootEntities()

Calling getRootAliases on a a QueryBuilder which has the `from` clause set will return an array of all aliases; similarly, calling getRootEntities will return an array of the shortened class names of the selected entities.

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->from('BundleName:EntityName', 'entityName');

var_dump($qb->getRootAliases()); // returns ['entityName']
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get alias with

```
 $alias = current($builder->getDQLPart('from'))->getAlias();
```

(where $builder is an instance of Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder)

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.5.0 doctrine queryBuilder had its getAllAliases() function made public. So you would basically simply get the array from :

```
$aliases = $builder->getAllAliases();
```

And retrieve an array like :

```
Array(
    [0] => p
    [1] => s
)
```